# Standard installation directory for an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, installation

I am deploying an ASP.NET application via a Wix installer. Is there a standard default installation directory such as `Program Files` or `C:\inetpub` or is it a matter of preference?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you install. 
You need to remember add

```
C:/Program Files/Windows Installer XML v3/bin
```

to System Path.